# How to email an element's value to an address

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I asked a question earlier that was taken down, but I have a better idea of what I want now and have an idea of the code I want to use. The idea is that the person will be able to enter an idea and it will email that idea to me when the form is submitted. This is what I've come up with using PHPMailer:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thesquid-ink-40-free-flat-icon-pack/64/rubber-duck-512.png" type="image/x-icon">
<title>Thank You!</title>
</head>
<body>
Your idea has been submitted! Thank you for the idea.
<a href="index.html"><button>Click to go back to the site!</button></a>
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'randomwordgenidea@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'ideaEmail';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('randomwordgenidea@gmail.com');
$mail->addAddress('randomwordgenidea@gmail.com');
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Idea';
$mail->Body    = echo $_GET["idea"];
$mail->AltBody = echo $_GET["idea"];
?>
</body>
<html>
```

This is the form I'm using to access the file:

```
<h1 style="color:grey">Ideas</h1>
<form action="email.php">
<h3>Idea:</h3>
<input type="text" name="idea">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

It doesn't work however, and I'm not sure if this I'm doing this correctly, if someone could debug the code for me, that would be great! Also, if anyone knows a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: You could try reading some docs, look at the Gmail example provided with PHPMailer. SO is not about debugging your code for you, it's to help you understand how to do it yourself.

Comment: @Synchro Stack Overflow allows debugging questions as long as they have, "the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." I will take a look at the gmail examples though and come back to you if there is still a problem.

Comment: Right, and you're missing most of those criteria.

Comment: @Synchro Well no, actually. I have the code in the shortest possible amounts as well as a clear purpose for the code. It doesn't matter though because I seem to have fixed the file with your suggestion, so I am hopefully not going to need further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in your code that actually **sends** your message.  [The PHPMailer docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) show a simple example, which shows how to actually send the msg you've constructed:

```
$mail->send();
```

Comment: That's helpful, I never really thought to add a send line, but it's a good thing you caught it.